# In XNA 3.1, is it possible to disable texture filtering?

Tags: xna, textures, filtering

I want to disable texture filtering (since I'm making a retro-style game where it looks bad if a texture gets filtered like that), but since I'm on XNA 3.1 there seems to be no option to set a `SamplerState` with `SpriteBatch.Begin` or anything. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Why don't you update at least to 3.1?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot i was actually on 3.1 >.>

Comment: I'd strongly suggest moving to XNA 4.0.

Comment: You should also update the question's title to 3.1 so it's clear.

Comment: @AndrewRussel: At this point, I have a nontrivial amount of shader interaction code written, and IIRC it's a pain to convert it. Moreover, I don't even really have room on my HDD right now for VS 2010 :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behaviour of `SpriteBatch` in XNA before 4.0 is rather ugly. Note that this answer only applies to XNA pre-4.0.

[This is a list of render states that `SpriteBatch` controls](https://web.archive.org/web/20150924160345/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2006/11/13/spritebatch-and-renderstates.aspx) (pre-4.0).

When `SpriteBatch` applies those settings depends on the `SpriteSortMode` parameter. The only reliable way to modify those settings is with `SpriteSortMode.Immediate`.

The way this works that, in immediate mode, `SpriteBatch` will set its render state when you call `Begin`. Immediately after calling `Begin` you can set your own render state, *before* you call `SpriteBatch.Draw`.

(States that `SpriteBatch` does not control can be set outside of the `Begin`/`End` block.)

The states you want to change (as r2d2rigo mentioned) are:

```
GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0].MagFilter = TextureFilter.Point;
GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0].MinFilter = TextureFilter.Point;
GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0].MipFilter = TextureFilter.Point;
```

Answer (score 0):

Call

```
GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0].MagFilter = TextureFilter.Point;
GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0].MinFilter = TextureFilter.Point;
GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0].MipFilter = TextureFilter.Point;
```

before using `SpriteBatch.Begin`. And remember to restore the values after `SpriteBatch.End`.

Comment: Not quite right. See my answer for a description of when to set those states.

Answer (score -1):

This is very possible. You can use a custom shader with spritebatch. The source to the default spritebatch shader is available from the XNA 'education catalog'. What you will need to do is get this shader and change the texture filtering in the shader from linear to point filtering, and then use your new version of the shader with spritebatch. To use it with spritebatch, call spritebatch.Begin, but set the sprite sort mode to immediate (This effectively means no batching). Then, apply the correct technique on your new effect. Then draw your sprites. Spritebatch will draw them immediately with whatever effect is currently applied.

IIRC using a custom shader with spritebatch is far simpler in XNA 4.0.

Comment: While this will actually work, compiling a custom shader is a bit of overkill when you can just change the render state directly.